# User authentication through private IP LDAP/Active Directory from website

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

For a project I need to authenticate users on the website with their LDAP credentials. The problem is, the LDAP server is on a **private IP** and the website is not withing the same network.
I already use the LDAP to log the users in the Intranet, which is on the same server as the LDAP.

Is there a way to communicate with the private LDAP from outside of the network ?

Some research seems to points to SSL connection, but I can't find a clear answer.

Any help is welcome.

Edit: Using a VPS worked out, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a virtual private network.
the answer lies [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2274028/3871208).

it will be independent of the os you are using.

Comment: The application is on an Apache server and the LDAP on a Windows one, if creating a tunnel with `ssh -L` is possible how do I tell the application to use it ?